# Domain Controller DNS alias

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, server-message-block

I recently updated an old Win2008R2-based domain to a new Win2019-based one (with the common promote / demote / decommission dance). This was for a very small office (3 peoples), so this is a single-DC setup where both the old and the new DCs doubled down as fileserver.

For this reason, I created a DNS alias to point the old name (ie: `olddc.example.com`) to the new one (ie: `newdc.example.com`). So far, so good: all client could reach the new DC/fileserver both with the old and the new names. However, I forget to formally add to the new DC the old DC's name (as an alias). In other words, I did not issue something similar to:

```
netdom computername newdc.example.com /add:olddc.example.com
```

Today I was on the new DC and, out of muscle memory, I tried to reach its own shares via the old names (opening Explorer and writing `\\olddc.example.com`). Explorer immediately complained about "wrong credendials" and, indeed, a Wireshark dump shown `STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`. I issued the `netdom` command above (adding `olddc.example.com` as an alias) and the problem went away: the server is now able to see its own shares via the old name.

I know and understand why the alternate/alias name should be added via `netdom` (or through a separate `setspn` command). However, what surprises me is that all the Win10 clients shown *no complains at all* even when such alternate name was not provided.

So, why do the Win10 clients worked with not issues at all while the server immediately walked back from accessing its own shares with a "unknown" DNS alias? Is it due to some different settings between Server and Client OSes? Or is it related to accessing a loopback share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loopback SMB connections are indeed treated differently from external ones: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/accessing-server-locally-with-fqdn-cname-alias-denied.

(The article references Windows Server 2003, but it still applies.)

Comment: I did not know about the loopback check! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Problem
   On Windows machines, file sharing can work via the computer name, with or without full qualification, or by the IP Address. By default, however, filesharing will not work with arbitrary DNS aliases. To enable filesharing and other Windows services to work with DNS aliases, you must make registry changes as detailed below and reboot the machine.
2. The Solution
   Allowing other machines to use filesharing via the DNS Alias (DisableStrictNameChecking)
   This change alone will allow other machines on the network to connect to the machine using any arbitrary hostname. (However this change will not allow a machine to connect to itself via a hostname, see BackConnectionHostNames below).

•   Edit the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters and add a value DisableStrictNameChecking of type DWORD set to 1.